# Sorting HashMap<String, Float> based on values in java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, compareto

How to sort HashMap  based on the values. I tried to overload compareTo method. But, I realized that I should be using Integer instead of Float

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: A HashMap is not sorted. Do you mean you want to have a list of all values in a sorted order?

Comment: Hope this link could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java

Comment: I have `public static HashMap<String,Float> cosineSim = new HashMap<String,Float> ();`  This needs to be sorted based on the value.

Comment: @AmukthaChakilam this link may be helps you https://gist.github.com/akhikhl/8153642

Comment: @KVK tried to overload Comparator but, I wasn't to do so because of the return type I hold, which is float and not int.